# Iterate over multiple list and creating list with outcome of result in Python

Tags: python

I am new in Python, before I worked on Perl and C.

I am running into simple problem, which can be easily nail down by the Python experts.

I have lists , the value on the list can be random.

```
list_a = [True, False]
list_b = [False, True]
list_c = [True]
```

I need to iterate over multiple list. I have researched and got the following working.

```
 output_list = []

 for i,j,k in map(None, list_a, list_b, list_c):

      output_list.append([i,j,k])
```

But the challenge I am facing challenge is After the output it is generating output something like this : `[(True,False,True), (False,True, None)]`

output_list[0] = [True,False,True]
output_list[1] = [False,True, None]

Expectation is should return give a clue about lists.

output_list[0] = [True_list_a,False_list_b,True_list_c]
output_list[1] = [False_list_a,True_list_b, None_list_c]

I have no clue of output I got output_list is of list_a or list_b or list_c.

How to create the output_list with corresponding list_a, list_b, list_c element, so that I can send to the function.

Is there any way to find it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what `ouput_list` should look like

Comment: what exact output do you expect?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, output_list should have a clue about elements of which list it is , like list_a, list_b and list_c. I am currently not getting how to create output_list to have clue of list_a, list_b and list_c. How to make it in more in pythonic way!?

Comment: Use `zip` instead of the `map(None,...)` idiom . That was outdated when `zip` was added to the language in Python 2.0, almost *20 years ago*

Comment: The output list has elements *from all three of the original lists*. I do not understand your confusion. Think about it this way, if you stacked up `list_a`,`list_b`, and `list_c` with `list_a` on top, so like a matrix, then the first "row" of `output_list` would be the first "column" of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. Perhaps, you wanted something like this(in regard with your comment *" ... output_list should have a clue about elements of which list it is"*):

```
import itertools

list_a = [True, False]
list_b = [False, True]
list_c = [True]

output_list = [{'list_a':t[0], 'list_b':t[1], 'list_c':t[2]}
               for t in itertools.zip_longest(list_a, list_b, list_c)]

print(output_list)
```

The output:

```
[{'list_a': True, 'list_b': False, 'list_c': True}, {'list_a': False, 'list_b': True, 'list_c': None}]
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, is this will work in Python2.7? I am seeing tupel index out of range.

Comment: @Sandy, welcome, for Python 2.7 you should replace `itertools.zip_longest` with `itertools.izip_longest`

Comment: Yes Thank you so much, I found the equilatent function as you said izip_longest and tried. But out list is returning only [{'list_a':False,'list_b':None,'list_c':False}] . I am I missing something?

Comment: @Sandy, I think that you have missed something. I've tested this on Python 2.7, works fine

Comment: Yes correct, works fine. I overlooked the solution. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like that:

```
import itertools
output_list = list(itertools.chain(list_a, list_b, list_c))
```

Comment: Edited the question for more detail, please do refer.